# How to include an overloaded operator << from another file in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, include, operator-overloading

I want to be able to print the contents of a vector in C++ by using operator overloading.

The operator overloading is defined as follows in the `debug.cpp` file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "debug.h"
#include "card.h"
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const vector<T> &vector)
{
        out << "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)vector.size(); i++) {
                out << vector[i];
                if (i < (int)vector.size() - 1) {
                        out << ",";
                }
        }
        out << "]";
        return out;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Card &card)
{
        out << "[" << card.category << "," << card.players << "]";
        return out;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Player &player)
{
        out << "[" << player.num_cards << "," << player.categories << "]";
        return out;
}
```

I also have a `debug.h` file which looks as follows.

```
#ifndef DEBUG_H
# define DEBUG_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "card.h"
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const vector<T> &vector);
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Card &card);
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Player &player);

#endif
```

This header file is used in my `main.cpp` file which looks as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "debug.h"
#include "card.h"
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

// Implementation intentially left blank for decluttering.
vector<Card> init_cards(const int &SET_SIZE, const int &NUM_SETS, const int &NUM_PLAYERS)
{

}

// Implementation intentially left blank for decluttering.
vector<Player> init_players(const int &SET_SIZE, const int &NUM_SETS, const int &NUM_PLAYERS)
{

}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
        int SET_SIZE = 4;
        int NUM_SETS = 3;
        int NUM_PLAYERS = 3;

        vector<Card> cards = init_cards(SET_SIZE, NUM_SETS, NUM_PLAYERS);
        vector<Player> players = init_players(SET_SIZE, NUM_SETS, NUM_PLAYERS);

        cout << cards << endl;    // [1]
        cout << players << endl;  // [2]

        return 0;
}
```

At the complete end of this file there are the lines [1] and [2] which should print the cards and the players vectors. However, this only works if I put the overloading function from the `debug.cpp` inside of the `main.cpp` file. The code shown here does not work and gives me the following error.

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-parameter -I inc -c -o obj/debug.o src/debug.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-parameter -I inc -c -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-parameter -I inc -o quaternity obj/debug.o obj/main.o
/usr/bin/ld: obj/main.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2b0): undefined reference to `std::ostream& operator<< <Card>(std::ostream&, std::vector<Card, std::allocator<Card> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to `std::ostream& operator<< <Player>(std::ostream&, std::vector<Player, std::allocator<Player> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:17: quaternity] Error 1
```

As can be seen the overloaded function cannot be found. How can I make it that the overloaded function will be found?

I already tried to put a `namespace std { ... }` statement around the declaration of the overloaded function but this did not work. The confusing thing is that all of this does work when I put the overloading functions in the `main.cpp` file but not when I include them from the `debug.cpp` file.

Comment: Put all your template definitions in debug.h

Comment: Template code must go in header files, otherwise you get link errors.

Comment: Thanks! You two are correct it works now. Can I ask why the template code has to be in the header files?

Comment: @borroot The linked post explains that.